My java code is generating Embedded XML tags
I'm trying to generate an xml file from java code. i have a simulation tag that contains a list of loans. But when i generate the xml file i get this structure:
<simulation>
    <loan>
        <loan>
        </loan>
        <loan>
        </loan>
    <loan>
</simalation>

when i need this structure:
<simulation>
    <loan>
    </loan>
    <loan>
    </loan>
</simalation>

I m lost :(

A good question of this type should show expected output (✔️),  actual output (✔️), input, and code (❌). We can't help unless and until we see the code that caused this.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. To better understand how to use this site, I suggest the following, with their links:  Tour, Help Center, How to Write a Good Question, and Minimal Reproducible Example.
